# Using version control git for ROS development

Tags: ros, best-practices, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am in favor of git in using version control. I would like to know the best practise to do it since I have my own node (myNode) in /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/myNode.

Should I wrapped the myNode folder/node with repo01.git(for example)? I mean the path now becomes /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/repo01.git/myNode.

Is there any better way doing it?

Thanks in advance..

-alfa-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9273/using-version-control-git-for-ros-development/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually one does not write new nodes or code in the `/opt/ros/<distro_release>/stacks/` area, but rather somewhere on the system when permissions are not an issue, e.g in the `/home/<user>/`, then you can let ros know of these packages but just doing `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:<path_to_own_packages>`. For version control, say git one can then easily set up using `git init` in the say `/home/<user>/packages` directory.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-03**:
Thanks a lot makokal :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use git for most of my ROS work and have no problems with it.

Some tips:

1. Don't keep your packages in /opt/ros... I like to keep my development code in a folder like `~/code/dev_stacks` and then I prepend that path to `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` in my `.bashrc`. See the [Setup](https://github.com/cwru-robotics/cwru-ros-pkg/wiki/Cwru-setup) page on the CWRU-ROS-PKG wiki for directions on how I had students in our Mobile Robotics course checkout the cwru-ros-pkg.
2. There is no need to change the directory name on your package to include the .git extension. Git URLS are the only place the .git extension to the repo name is actually used to my knowledge.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-03**:
Thanks a lot Eric :-)

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-03**:
I think it may just be bare repositories that need the .git extension. See http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/creating-local-git-repositories-yeah-its-that-simple and note that they create a bare repo with the .git extension. This bare repo would *not* go on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-03**:
Pertaining #2. i think our repository has to be with extension .git? Can someone correct me..By the way, I intend to do version control only locally, not  on github. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We use git for our version control and this is what we do:

1. First, make sure you get familiar with the concepts of repositories, stacks, and packages as they pertain to ROS:

   http://www.ros.org/wiki/Repositories
   http://www.ros.org/wiki/Stacks
   http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages

   Name your repository. The accepted model is to name it something along the lines of "foo-ros-pkg". If the repo is part of an institution, like a company or a university, "foo" can be the name of that group. If it's a personal repo, "foo" can be your initials, last name, or something similar.

   Name your stacks and packages. You can check out here for more info:

   http://www.ros.org/wiki/Naming

   You should try to be descriptive as to what the stack/package is, and also try not to clash with other existing stacks, in case you decide to make your code public at some point.

   Organize your directories. Your repository should contain the stacks, and the stacks contain the packages. As an example: our repo is called "ccny-ros-pkg". It has a "scan_tools" stack, which in turn contains a "canonical_scan_matcher" package. So I store it in:

   ```
   ~/ros/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/canonical_scan_matcher
   ```

   Note that "~/ros" does not have to be your ROS installation directory. As the other answers pointed out, you usually install ROS binaries in "/opt/ros", but you can keep your development work in "~/ros", where you have write permissions.

   Prepend "~/ros/" to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in your setup.sh file, located in your ros installation directory. For example, mine contains these lines:

   ```
   export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks
   export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}
   ```

   Apply version control. Usually, you would put you whole repository under version control, ie, foo-ros-pkg. If you are using git, you can simply do:

   ```
   cd ~/ros/foo-ros-pkg
   git init
   ```

   This will create a hidden ".git" folder inside "foo-ros-pkg". It will contain your local repository.

Hope this helps!
Ivan

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-09**:
@Ivan Dryanovski: Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once everything is configured, you may also use rosinstall with git in creating a *.rosinstall file. If you publish it on the web http:/mysite/mystack.rosinstall user will be able to install the stack easily. Here is the orocos_toolchain_ros example :

orocos_toolchain_ros.rosinstall:

- git:
  local-name: orocos_toolchain_ros
  uri: http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/orocos_toolchain_ros.git

rosinstall [path] http:/mysite/mystack.rosinstall

---

Originally posted by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) with karma: 352 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1